# Android Tablet Refuse to Enter Recovery Mode

Tags: boot

One of my Tablet(ET-86V2G-A23) refuse to enter recovery mode. I did long press volume up and power switch together and nothing happens and I also tried holding down volume up, plugging in USB cable to PC, tap power switch up to 10 times and then release volume up. That didn't work too. I want to flash the Tablet because it stops at boot flash screen. Are there any other method to force it to boot mode?

I also figure out that kernel version in `system/bin/sh` keeps failing.

Is it possible to rewrite files in `system/bin` via adb using command. I think it may also solve the start up problem. I can remember the problem started after installing busybox. Seems something went wrong after installation.

Comment: Are you rooted?  Have you tried `adb reboot recovery`?

Comment: The Tablet is rooted.  `adb reboot recovery` just did a restart and came back to the flash screen. I tried tools like GpGtool and it did the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing a firmware upgrade with phoenix flash tool. I also figured out that there is a lot of fake firmware that do not work. they are just empty .img files.